# I do not understand how to use jni in cocos2dx

Tags: java-native-interface, cocos2d-x

Hello and sorry for my broken English :)

I started working with cocox2d, and it became necessary to use jni for android. I know how to create *.h as invoke methods of C + +, but I do not understand how this is all done in cocos2dx. If anyone has encountered the problem, could you write an algorithm to explain or order :) I would be very grateful.

Answer (score 1):

There is no specific algorithm for it.. Its just a process..
You can learn it in an efficient manner using this [link](http://blog.molioapp.com/2011/11/openfeint-and-admob-integrated-with.html)

Its a great tutorial to understand its use.. I also learnt from here. Try to look into MessageJni.cpp file. You will come to know how to call android methods from your scene.. Hope this helps... :)